# pjax breaks jquery.chosen

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, pjax, jquery-chosen

I use jquery chosen plugin for multiple select control, when I include pjax into my project, chosen doesn't work after I redirect to link. 
But if I press F5 chosen now works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened because chosen is applied on document ready event. When smth updated by Ajax document ready event isn't triggered. You should apply chosen after Ajax complete. For example in coffeescript:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete ->
  $('select').chosen()
```

Comment: Thanks for idea, in my case $(document).on "pjax:end" -> $("#xxx").chosen()